# How to take every pixel color of a photo

Tags: css, image, jpeg, pixel

I am practicing in CSS and I want to divide any photo by every pixel color and to "draw" it in css. What is the fastest way to take every pixel color of a photo?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by you want to divide a photo by every pixel color?

Comment: Work with HTML5 Canvas Image and put every pixel of your image in an array. Then remove color duplicates and you got yourself what you need! Note that you'll need javascript to do that, I don't think this is possible using HMTL or CSS only.

Comment: _"...way to take every pixel color of a photo?"_  are you trying to create a colour **palette** for a given image? Something like this **[image](http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/average-colours-710x399.jpg)** or what this **[website](http://www.degraeve.com/color-palette/)** is doing? Don't worry about the "fastest" way. All you can do is make a `for-loop` to check every pixel and list only unique colours. It will be as fast as device/browser allows. PS: Show some code of what you've tried. You'll get faster help that way...